# would this constitute kufr?

Tags: halal-haram, jannah, evil-thoughts

I understand that God doesn’t punish us for any thoughts that we have, but I’m confused on if having anger towards a part of Islam would make one a kufr or not. I came across something about men having 72 hoors in paradise and that women will only be able to be with their husbands and that made me a bit upset and angry. I took away these feelings and I don’t feel upset about it anymore because I understand the reason but I’m still worried. Would this count as hating on a part of Islam/kufr?

Comment: Question title and content (the question asked) are in conflict. The topic of the so called 72 hoors is addressed on the site.

Comment: okay thank you i’ve made some changes

Answer (score 0):

It does have an effect on islam. You have to understand that islam is a composite word made up of five meanings:

surrender, summission, obedience, submit and peace.

And the peace does not mean what you might think. It means peace within our self with what God decides. And this you should have if you believe God is All Knowing, All Powerfull, All wise, etc... so it is also linked to belief.

I personally could not get angry toward islam/Allah as I love and fear Allah too much.